# PDO not returning any rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This setting isn't returning anything from the database. It's my first time using PDO, so I'm probably missing something. It's not throwing any errors at all, just an empty result.

```
$results = array();

$stmt = $bd->prepare("Select Beer.Beer_Name, Prices.Price, Prices.Shop_Name FROM Beer, Prices WHERE Beer.Beer_Name = Prices.Beer_Name AND Shop_Id = :retailer");

    $stmt->bindValue(':retailer', $retailer);


$stmt->execute();



$results[0] = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($results[0]);
```

Comment: Problem 1 - you might not be catching errors correctly. Set PDO in Exception mode, wrap your code with try/catch. Problem 2 - $retailer might be empty, or there simply isn't the record you want that matches your $retailer. Tip 1 - always test your queries in MySQL terminal or another MySQL GUI tool so you are sure your query will succeed and so you have something to debug with.

Comment: Yep, I printed $retailer and it was set, and I ran the query on the database manually and it returned a row.

Comment: Have a db connection. Display errors. Use explicit join.

Comment: It's properly normalised, I'm just testing connections on it. Problem solved, typo in database name.

Comment: The exception mode previous commenters are referring to is `$bd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` to be placed just after you do `$bd = new PDO(...)`. By default, PDO errors silently.

Comment: It is de-normalized... i can tell from the pseudo join. Can u spot it?

Comment: It is also possible to set `ERRMODE_WARNING`, in which it will behave a little more like `mysqli` or `mysql_*()`, but exception mode is really the most versatile, as you can wrap everything in `try/catch` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the array before hand, and you can check for results before using `$query->RowCount()`.  Here is an example using error catching:

```
try {
    // Enabled throwing errors - you can remove this after debugging
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    // Prepare the statement
    $stmt = $bd->prepare("Select Beer.Beer_Name, Prices.Price, Prices.Shop_Name FROM Beer, Prices WHERE Beer.Beer_Name = Prices.Beer_Name AND Shop_Id = :retailer");

    // You can also use bindparams, I like to use execute and pass and array so it is shorter
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':retailer' => $retailer
    ));
    if($stmt->RowCount()==0) {
        // Do stuff when no results are found (without an error)
    } else {
        $Results = $stmt->FetchAll();
    }

// Catch any exceptions and put the error into $e
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Echo the error we got - you should only output errors when debugging
    echo $e->GetMessage();
}
```

Let me know if you have questions, but this method should give you any database errors.  If you don't get errors, your query simply isn't returning anything.

Comment: No, you never use `rowCount` because it's not accurate and it might not work. You execute, if that fails - exception occurs. Then you `fetchAll` and count the elements in the array, which is how you obtain "row count". Alternatively, you can check the result of `$stmt->execute()` and if  returns true you can `fetchAll`.

Comment: @N.B. I just researched it a bit, looks like you're right.  I've never had an issue with RowCount on Mysql but other databases could handle it differently according to the docs.  Thanks for the tip

Comment: The problem is that even MySQL can report it wrong. You probably won't experience the issue on 99.9% of MySQL deployments, but the fact that it's not reliable - that's bad. If you can edit your answer to include counting the size of array with rows instead of `rowCount`, I'll be more than happy to upvote you.